# Add users (members) to Azure Active Directory that isn't of a verified domain name in the directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal

When I try to add a user with a login that's a regular email address like john@gmail.com, I have the following message on the right:

`'gmail.com' is not a verified domain name in this directory`

I want them to be able to authenticate without a name like 'john@MyApp.onmicrosoft.com'. I read an answer that said this isn't possible, but I can see gmail and outlook email addresses that someone else added (they aren't around). They are members, not guests. How do you add users like that?

Comment: serverfault.com would be the site for this question https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add Guest User is the button you are looking for.

It allows you to add users with any email address.

Comment: How come these are members and not guests?

Comment: Hmm, it might be possible to change the type afterwards. But I can say the portal UI won't allow you to add them as members directly.

Comment: I could not change the user guest type afterward.